# How assign static ip to centOS 7?

Tags: bash, networking, centos7

I am using centOS 7 and my machine is changing IP randomly on restart. So, I want to assign IP static to get-rid from further changes on other areas.

For example I have to change ip address again and again in putty settings. etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can check your IP and subnetmask details from your machine with command

```
ifconfig
```

**1st Solution :**

Create a file named /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 as follows:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
PREFIX=24
IPADDR=192.004.6.123
```

Restart network service: systemctl restart network

**2nd Solution :**

Open default file vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33
and modify you settings according to below settings

```
IPADDR=192.004.6.123
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BROADCAST=192.169.7.255
BOOTPROTO="static"
```

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the following steps to assign static IP in CentOs7

vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=192.168.7.203
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BROADCAST=192.168.7.255
NETWORK=192.168.7.0
GATEWAY=192.168.7.245
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="eth0"
UUID="696cc3d6-ac01-453b-967c-7decf10e6e6a"
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
ZONE=public
```

Now restart network interface by "service network restart"

its all done.